# test if JAXB generated field is required

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I have a JAXB generated class PersonType with the properties name, phone, address. In the XSD I define that "phone" minoccurs="1".
How can I test programatically(i.e. via reflection, etc), in Java code, if the property "phone" is required or not in the XSD?

Later edit: 
The JAXB generator creates a class without any "required", etc. attributes. So there's no annotation on the class or it's fields to indicate if it's required or not. However, there's the @XmlElement annotation on the field specifying the XSD equivalent element. So I guess the only solution is to inspect this annotation and then make an XPath or something against the XSD?

Thank you!

Comment: You want to test that the class contains `@XmlElement(required=true)` or you want to test that an instance of the class has the require `name` element?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/#

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I need a way to test if that field is required or not in the XSD-side. In the Java generated class, there's no indication of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `@XmlElement` annotation has a `required` property (false by default) that is used to indicate that an XML element is required (`minOccurs` > 0).  You could use the `java.lang.reflect` APIs to get this value from the class.

**XML Schema**

In the XML schema below the `foo` element is required and the `bar` element is not.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="root">
        <sequence>
            <element name="foo" type="string"/>
            <element name="bar" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**Generated Class**

Below is the class that was generated from the XML schema.  We see that the `foo` field is annotated with `@XmlElement(required=true)` anf the `bar` field is not.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "root", propOrder = {
    "foo",
    "bar"
})
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String foo;

    protected String bar;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a good solution, however if these fields are part of a restriction from a base type, JAXB doesn't generate any metadata for the "extended" type. The fields are defined only in the base type(in Java code).

Comment: @leadgy - You can use reflection to inspect inherited fields/properties as well.  You can also get a classes super class and inspect that directly as well.

Comment: It's just that if you restrict from a parent type, the restrictions set in the child type don't appear in the generated Java code. So I'm not sure how's that possible with reflection. Thanks!